# What is the equation relating maximum data transfer rates for a given EM bandwidth?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light

I was looking for an equation that could show the relationship between the range of frequencies of an EM wave, and its Maximum data transfer rate. I know that ranges of shorter wavelengths can have a larger bitrate/symbol rate, but could not find an equation relating the two variables.

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT: I refined my wording above. Also, no one answered my question over at amateur radio SE. As for the nyquist rate wiki page, I still could not find the answer I was looking for.

Comment: The bandwidth of a given frequency is zero.

Comment: @HotLicks could you clarify what you mean? Did I misspeak?

Comment: "Bandwidth" refers to the range of adjacent frequencies occupied by some signal.

Comment: Oh yes, but I was using the computational definition: "The maximum rate of data transfer across a given path" @HotLicks

Comment: Right.  And the way you transfer data is by varying the carrier frequency.

Comment: Data rates (or symbol rates) and bandwidth are also not the same.  Symbol rates can be increased and still not expand the physically occupied bandwidth.  For info on refining your question see:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_rate and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate

Comment: suggest you migrate this to the amateur radio SE. you will find experts there on the relationship between carrier frequency, bit rate, and bandwidth requirements.

Comment: @nielsnielsen I'm sorry, I didn't get the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [Shannon-Hartley Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem?wprov=sfti1), which describes the upper bound on the information sent over a noisy channel:

$$
C = B \log_2 ( 1 + S / N ) 
$$

Where S/N is the signal to noise ratio of the channel, B is the bandwidth in Hz, and C is the information rate in bits/second.  This result assumes Gaussian white noise.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel silly for not finding the wiki page, but am glad you were able to be such a respectful lifesaver